# Improvements on cookie based session management

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

"Instead of using cookies for authorization, server operators might
wish to consider entangling designation and authorization by treating
URLs as capabilities.  Instead of storing secrets in cookies, this
approach stores secrets in URLs, requiring the remote entity to
supply the secret itself.  Although this approach is not a panacea,
judicious application of these principles can lead to more robust
security." A. Barth
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265

What is meant by storing secrets in URLs? How would this be done in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique that I believe fits this description is requiring clients to request [URLs that are signed with HMAC](http://rc3.org/2011/12/02/using-hmac-to-authenticate-web-service-requests/). Amazon Web Services offers this technique for some operations, and I have seen it implemented in internal APIs of web companies as well. It would be possible to sign URLs server side with this or a similar technique and deliver them securely to the client (over HTTPS) embedded in HTML or in responses to XMLHttpRequests against an API.

As an alternative to session cookies, I'm not sure what advantage such a technique would offer. However, in some situations, it is convenient or often the best way to solve a problem. For example, I've used similar techniques when:

**Cross Domain**

You need to give the browser access to **a URL that is on another domain**, so cookies are not useful, and you have the capability to sign a URL server side to give access, either on a redirect or with a long enough expiration that the browser has time to load the URL.

***Examples***: Downloading files from S3. Progressive playback of video from CloudFront.

**Closed Source Limitations**

You can't control what the browser or other client is sending, aside from the URL, because you are working with **a closed source plugin** of some kind and can't change its behavior. Again you sign the URL server side so that all the client has to do is GET the URL.

***Examples***: Loading video captioning and/or sprite files via WEBVTT, into a closed-source Flash video player. Sending a payload along with a federated single sign-on callback URL, when you need to ensure that the payload can't be changed in transit.

**Credential-less Task Worker**

You are sending a URL to something other than a browser, and that something needs to access the resource at that URL, and on top of that **you don't want to give it actual credentials**.

***Example***: You are running a queue consumer or task-based worker daemon or maybe an AWS Lambda function, which needs to download a file, process it, and send an email. Simply pre-sign all the URLs it will use, with a reasonable expiration, so that it can perform all the requests it needs to without any additional credentials.

Comment: Something like this then: https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/503824/1/p2171-de_ryck.pdf

Comment: Actually the technique in the paper you link to differs significantly from what I describe above. The paper's technique, which they call SecSess, uses a shared secret on the client side to sign URLs. In my examples I'm suggesting signing URLs only on the server.

Comment: I don't think the linked paper's SecSess technique "stores secrets in URLs" because the browser stores the shared secret somewhere (they just say "stored in the browser"), even if it's just in memory.

Comment: In your link http://rc3.org/2011/12/02/using-hmac-to-authenticate-web-service-requests/ they also talk about calculating the HMAC of the body of a request at client side.
I have looked into AWS S3 that adds a HMAC to a request. It's similar to SecSess in implementation but used a preshared secret.
Also why do you believe this remark in the RFC means server side signing of the URL? I don't entirely understand your answer.

Comment: I don't think the comment is specifically referring to the HMAC technique, but the phrase "this approach stores secrets in URLs" precludes a pre-shared secret, or the storage of a secret somewhere other than in URLs (for example, in memory, in cookies, in local storage, etc.). I think what the author is referring to is a technique where the server gives a URL to the client that contains a secret and is therefore more than just a resource pointer but also contains the ability to take an action on that resource ("treating URLs as capabilities"). Server-side signing fits that description.

Comment: That's not to say that a pre-shared secret is a worse approach. We use the S3 / CloudFront signed URL technique with great results in a variety of situations, and we've used client-side signing of URLs in an OAuth2 context. But for standard user-login-authenticated web applications, I still think the session cookie approach works great. The browser security model is well tested, TLS is popular and fairly commoditized at this point, despite several recently-identified flaws/upgrades, and security teams know how to test for vulnerabilities within that paradigm.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your elaborate answer. Do you really feel that there are no security treats coming from the bearer token property of SID in cookies? I thought adoption rate of TLS wasn't that great.

Comment: I'm not saying there are no threats! There are lots of threats: CSRF, XSSI, injections of other kinds, etc. My point is that I feel I have techniques available to protect against them and also to test those protections, including vendors who will help me test it. Of course I hope that a better technique arises and is adopted enough to challenge session cookies as the current state of the art.

Comment: When I said "TLS is popular and fairly commoditized" what I mean is that the many tools I use support it pretty well, with implementations that are both mature and up to date with recent threats. Whether other sites in the web ecosystem have adopted it is more an issue of public health than of architecture.